# python schedule to run another file.py every certain time

Tags: python-3.x, import, while-loop, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have a python script in file called `tasks.py` containing multiple tasks, processes and functions (and it works perfect to me).

i want to run this file (`tasks.py`) at certain time ( 1:00 am & 4:45 am & 11:35 am & 6:25 pm & 9:10 pm) every day starting from date say as example 6 aug 2018.

so i created a new file and called it `run.py`

i used the following code to import `tasks.py` file

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import tasks
```

but i want to schedule this import in the certain times as mentioned above starting from the required date

i tried `while` function, `schedule` module, `cron` module and `import os` but i failed with all

any body can help please ????

Answer (score 2):

The simple solution can be something like that

```
import datetime
from time import sleep

rest_seconds = 3600  # sleep for one hour, so the task won't be called few times per hour
while True:
    if datetime.datetime.now().hour == 12:
        do_task()
    sleep(rest_seconds)
```

If you need a complex one, I use [Airflow](http://airflow.readthedocs.io) framework for building scheduled tasks/pipelines

Comment: thanks dear for your answer, it was helpful and i will try it soon, i have a question if you don't mind, the file `tasks.py` containing a lot of def , equations and data-frames, how can i create a def in run.py file to run the `tasks.py` with all it's contents, like `def foo: return import file.py` or something similar